# Cloud SQL and HTTP Load Balancing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-sql

One of the higher SKUs costs I have in my project is related to HTTP Load Balancing: Global Forwarding Rule Minimum Service Charge in my single Cloud SQL instance.

In this context, I'm wondering why a HTTP Load Balancing is being charged for a single database? Is this something related to how some of my services use Cloud SQL Proxy to access the database?

Comment: Forwarding rules are link to LB, not to any database.Cloud SQL and HTTPs LB are different products.Even though if you link your LB to cloud SQL that will not incur any extra cost. I would recommend to review the forwarding rules in the project using the gcloud command[1] to find out how many forwarding rules you might have in his project.Contd..

Comment: As suggested by Martin Zeitlet, I would also suggest to use private IP. For more information and queries, regarding costs associated with project you can reach out to the cloud billing team.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/list
[2]https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/

Answer (score 0):

why you even need this [global forwarding rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/global-forwarding-rules) for Cloud SQL? use [private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip) to access it.